# How to get the values of dynamically created checkbox android?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I created checkboxes dynamically(as response from api). Now I need to get the values of checkboxes those are checked. Here is my code.

```
private HashMap<Integer,String> answerMap= new HashMap<>();

for (int i = 1; i <= formsData.get(position).getValues().size(); i++) {
                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(mContext);
                Forms forms = formsData.get(position);
                checkBox.setText(formsData.get(position).getValues().get(i - 1));
                checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            answerMap.put(formsData.get(position).getQuestionId(),checkBox.getText().toString());
                        } else {
                            answerMap.remove(formsData.get(position).getQuestionId());
                            System.out.println("map size: " + answerMap.size());
                        }
                        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : answerMap.entrySet()) {
                            Integer key = entry.getKey();
                            String value = entry.getValue();
                            System.out.println("question id : " + key + " answer : " + value);

                        }
                    }
                });
```

but here if more than one checkbox is checked I'm only getting the value of last checked item. Anyone help me

Answer (score 2):

Create a list before your loop: `ArrayList<CheckBox> array = new ArrayList<>();` 
After each creation of a checkbox add it to the list: `array.add(checkBox);` 
Now you have all your checkboxes in the list and you can loop through them to find which are checked:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
        if (array.get(i).isChecked()) {
            Log.i("mine", i + " is checked");
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you help me how to use listeners for this array of checkboxes

Comment: This array is used outside of these listeners if you want to keep track of all the checkboxes, after the user has made his selections. You use the listeners to do something the moment the user selects or unselects a checkbox.

Comment: without this listener, I won't get this data in my activity. NB: this is from my adapter code

Comment: Tell me exactly what you have to do: do you want to make all the needed changes after the user has made all his selections or every time he checks a checkbox?

Comment: After all the changes user made

Comment: Then you don't need the listeners. Put all the code you need (now present in the listener) in a loop like the one I have in my answer and by checking if each checkbox is checked or not do your stuff.